# Connecting Motor wiring

Tags: wiring, electric-motor, blinds

[image: Device Connection diagram]

I'm trying to connect Live Wires (L/N/G) to this electric blind receiver and can't figure out the way to do it. Motor Has 4 Wires

1. Blue = Neutral
2. Black = Direction 1 (I assume UP or Down)
3. Brown = Direction 2 (I assume UP or Down)
4. Green/Yellow = Earth

If someone can shine some light on how do I connect this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it seems completely straightforward:

```
tien li kou huo xien <--> xien xiu qi "L" t'ou
tien li kou leng xien <--> xien xiu qi "N" t'ou

tien tung ma t'a lan xien <--> xien xiu qi "N" t'ou 
tien tung ma t'a huang xien <--> xien xiu qi "A" t'ou 
tien tung ma t'a hei xien <--> xien xiu qi "B" t'ou
```

and of course

```
tien tung ma t'a qing xien <--> tien li kou ku chiang (qing) xien
```

[image: at least the diagram is in english]

I can't imagine why anyone would be confused by this.

Comment: First of all thank you for the explanation. I just have a quick question what is A N B stands for?

Comment: 'A' winding (one-direction), 'B' winding (t'other-direction) and 'N', neutral (common) connection.